# FInding Duplicate records in a table and deleting those records using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table named "cities" which has columns "ID", "state" and "cities". There are some duplicate records found in the table. I want those records to be found and deleted from the table. Note that the query should found and delete the record only if both the state and city names are same.How this can be done using postgreSQl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is unique (as implied by your question), you can use `delete` with `id`:

```
delete from cities c
    where c.id > (select min(c2.id)
                  from cities c2
                  where c2.state = c.state and c2.cities = c.cities
                 );
```

If the `id` can also be the same, you can use `ctid`:

```
delete from cities c
    where c.ctid > (select min(c2.ctid)
                    from cities c2
                    where c2.state = c.state and c2.cities = c.cities and
                          c2.id = c.id
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff for the response. The above query keeps on running and never stopped. FYI, The table has around 1 lakh records.

Comment: You could try to limit the load on the server by partitioning the data in the inner query, adding something like `AND c2.id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000`, then moving the window. The appropriate size of the window, you need to find out.

Comment: @harinish . . . That isn't very many records.  You probably just need an index on `cities(state, cities)` -- and perhaps `id` at the end as well.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks. I created a unique index and then performed the query. It run successfully.