# Remove duplicate records with same ID - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Wondering if it is possible to keep just one record from duplicates. In this scenario, the ID is also duplicate. I know the best way is that ID is unique, but in this scenario is not. Then, I have three records like these ones:

| id | name | point | closest_community_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Secondary School | POINT (-121.94291423 49.17457331) | 126 |
| 1 | Secondary School | POINT (-121.94291423 49.17457331) | 126 |
| 1 | Secondary School | POINT (-121.94291423 49.17457331) | 126 |

I can find the duplicates with this query:

```sql
    select id, name, point, closest_community_id  
    from primary_location pl 
    group by pl.id, name, point, closest_community_id
    having count(pl.id) > 1
```

But how can I keep just one record from the duplicates when they have the same ID?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FInding Duplicate records in a table and deleting those records using postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231963/finding-duplicate-records-in-a-table-and-deleting-those-records-using-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks @MikeOrganek, this question is different. Usually, the scenarios are as the one mentioned in the link. In that link the scenario is "the query should found and delete the record only if both the state and city names are same". In my case, also the id is the same,, so id cannot be compared like in the example  `c.ctid > (select min(c2.ctid)`. Thanks

Comment: The CTID is not the same as the ID.  CTID is a system column and is guaranteed unique for each row:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#:~:text=transaction%2C%20or%20zero.-,ctid,-The%20physical%20location

Comment: On a side note: Don't call a column `id`, when it's not the table's unique ID.

Comment: Good point @ThorstenKettner, sometimes we do not have the luxury to decide it when we join to the party late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ctid:

```
delete from primary_location pl
where exists
(
  select null
  from primary_location pl2
  where pl2.id = pl.id
  and pl2.name = pl.name
  and pl2.point = pl.point
  and pl2.closest_community_id = pl.closest_community_id
  and pl2.ctid > pl.ctid
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try

```
select distinct id, name, point, closest_community_id  
from primary_location pl
```